# Why isn't my web page locating the address of my image which I have given to the body?

Tags: angular5

This is the error while loading:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   C:/UsersSANGEETHngprosrcssetsimg%13.png.

*index.html:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angpro</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(src\assets\img\13.png)">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem: The image is not displayed. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the image path as this. It will work.
 Always use forward slash instead of backward slash to specify a particular path